# Building MonoGame Framework for Mac OS

Tags: mono, monodevelop, monogame

I'm getting ready to port a game, and it's my first time. I'm running Windows 7 and have the latest version of MonoGame from github as well as MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2.

When I try to load the MonoGame.Framework.MacOS solution in MonoDevelop, it fails to load and gives me this error:
Could not load project 'MonoGame\MonoGame.Framework\MonoGame.Framework.MacOS.csproj' with unknown item type '{948B3504-5B70-4649-8FE4-BDE1FB46EC69};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}'

Something similar happens when I try to open the iOS solution. I was able to build the Windows, Linux, and Android solutions successfully, however.

Please advise!

Comment: I think you need to install MonoDevelop on a Mac OS X machine and then open the project. If a project has MacOS in its name, it may not work on any other operating system.

Comment: Thank you! That might explain it, I didn't think of that. Unfortunately I don't have access to a Mac at this time to test it on, but in a month or two I should.

Answer (score 0):

i'd just look at https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3714 and copy this line: xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd"

over the xmlns=...." of this file
MonoGame-develop/MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline/MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.MacOS.csproj

So next I`d built the project successfully. 
After all, I'd take the .dlls generated at folder MonoGame.Framework/bin/MacOS/Release and referenced them in my Game project(I'd deleted the older references too).

I hope that it can help you!